# How to put a mandatory check if all environment variables are set in vue js application

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, environment-variables, frontend

How can we make sure before building a vue js application that all environment variables values are set that are mentioned in .env.example ?

Comment: This depends on what you are building the application with. Please also describe the build process.. Vue CLI I am assuming?

Comment: Yes with Vue CLI @PeterKrebs

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to write a shell script which imports the `.env` and checks the environment variables.

You can edit `package.json` and add that script (let's call it `check-env.sh` to the `scripts` section:

```json
{
  
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "./check-env.sh && vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "./check-env.sh && vue-cli-service build",
    "dev": "./check-env.sh && vue-cli-service build --mode development",
    "watch-dev": "./check-env.sh && vue-cli-service build --watch --mode development",
    "watch": "./check-env.sh && vue-cli-service build --watch --mode production",
    "lint": "./check-env.sh && vue-cli-service lint"
  },
}
```

That could be made more elegant with a Webpack plugin, for example, but gives you the option to turn it on and off for the above scripts.

You can add a [configureWebpack](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html#simple-configuration) method to your `vue.config.js` and make the script a proper module instead, to make it mandatory for each build.
This way you could import it in your `vue.config.js` and add a call to configureWebpack() which throws an exception if the env variables are not as expected.

```js
// vue.config.js

// Import your script along the other imports in this file...

module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: config => {
    // Call the check here and throw an exception. This should work.
    
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
      // mutate config for production...
    } else {
      // mutate for development...
    }
  }
}
```